# twig nested loop getting more elements

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a nested loop in twig and i get the elements doubled in the form of 1,1,1,1 / 2,2,2,2 / 3,3,3,3. How can i use the first loop to access the data from the second loop without duplicating the elements ?

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {% for question in surveyQuestions %}
        <div class="overlay-container tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="show-rendered-form tab-pane in fade active" id="show-rendered-form">
                {% form_theme form with ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'] %}
                {{ form(form) }}
                <div class="overlay-mask">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="edit-action btn btn-default" href="#show-edit-form"
                           data-question-id="{{ question.id }}" aria-controls="show-rendered-form"
                           role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Editeaza</a>
                        <a class="delete-action btn btn-default" href="#show-rendered-form"
                           data-question-id="{{ question.id }}" aria-controls="" role="tab"
                           data-toggle="tab">Sterge</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="show-edit-form tab-pane" id="show-edit-form">

            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do.. Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: well i have a set of forms that i want to display on a page and in the same time i need to display some data between the forms.

Comment: Okay so to get this straight: You have n forms and n questions. After each form should be one related question. the forms and questions are in corresponding order. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my assessment above is correct: Why not do it like this?

Instead of using a foreach loop, we use a classical for loop and use the index as identifier for both, `forms` and `surveyQuestions`:

```
{% for i in 0..(forms|length - 1)%}
        <div class="overlay-container tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="show-rendered-form tab-pane in fade active" id="show-rendered-form">
                {% form_theme form with ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'] %}
                {{ form(forms[i]) }}
                <div class="overlay-mask">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="edit-action btn btn-default" href="#show-edit-form"
                           data-question-id="{{ surveyQuestions[i].id }}" aria-controls="show-rendered-form"
                           role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Editeaza</a>
                        <a class="delete-action btn btn-default" href="#show-rendered-form"
                           data-question-id="{{ surveyQuestions[i].id }}" aria-controls="" role="tab"
                           data-toggle="tab">Sterge</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="show-edit-form tab-pane" id="show-edit-form">

            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Key "4" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist in form_container.html.twig at line 4 of course i did the modification there and modified form with forms[i]

Comment: Ahh sorry, of course not. I forgot to subtract 1 from the length. I will update my answer

Comment: yeap this one works :-D but may i know why that error with the key ? didn't quite understand it.

Comment: `length` gives you the number of elements in forms, which is 4. The elements themselves are 0-indexed, which means that the index start at 0.
So with 4 elements, you have the indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3. but we tried to access indexes 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 (because that was the length).

Comment: ohh i see :d didn't know this one.